# Fundamental difference between Join() Lock()

Tags: c#, multithreading

For the case of both Join() and lock() one thread can execute after the other.What is the main difference?

Answer (score 11):

Lock is a monitor which is used to guarantee that only 1 thread can execute at a time.

```
lock(myobj)
{
   // only 1 thread here
}
```

Join is used to wait for a thread to complete, before execution continues.

```
anotherThread.Join();
// execution here only when anotherThread is complete
```

Answer (score 3):

`Thread.Join()` waits for a thread to *exit*. `Monitor.Enter(obj)` (how the compiler expresses the entry to a `lock` statement) waits for no other thread to hold `obj`'s object lock.

The former is used to help manage thread lifetimes, the latter to control concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

In the below code, the second thread waits for the first thread to exit. So, the first thread starts and gets completed before second thread starting.

```
public void threadExample1()
{
    Thread t1=new Thread(fun1);
    Thread t2=new Thread(fun2);

    t1.Start();
    t1.Join();

    t2.Start();
}
```

In the second example, we don't know which thread will start first, but we know there is only one thread will run at a time because of `lock`

```
public readonly object locker = new object();
public void threadExample2()
{
   Thread t1=new Thread(fun1);
   Thread t2=new Thread(fun2);

   t1.Start();
   t2.Start();
}

public void fun1()
{ 
   lock(locker)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         Console.Write("1");
   }
}
public void fun2()
{ 
   lock(locker)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         Console.Write("2");
   }
}
```

the output will be either "11111111112222222222" or "22222222221111111111" for lock example while only "11111111112222222222" for Join example